# WP Rest api v2 disable accessing data in another site

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-api

I am developing a blogging site using `Wordpress as backend` and `Laravel as frontend` with the help of `WP Rest api v2` but i am having trouble with data accessing authentication.

My website have been developed but problem is that i want my website content could not be accessed by another site using `http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2` url.
Example:

```
http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

using above url i can access posts data but i want to restrict another server from accessing data in their website.

Comment: try disable rest api plugin or force authenticate users only can access your wp api